# Amazon RDS Postgres consumed all free storage, dropping by 700GB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We recently had an incident where free storage dropped from 700GB to near zero. We're trying to understand what might have happened. Any ideas what could cause such a huge drop in available storage? As far as I'm aware we weren't running anything abnormal at the time, though it's now a couple of weeks after so finding what was running is tricky. Anybody know where we might be able to look? We have performance insights enabled for 1 week, so that's not available anymore. We're running engine version 12.8 on a db.r5.large instance.

[Graph of free storage space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgHVC.png)

Comment: As cited in this response, there could be some temp tables getting created as part of complex query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672876/amazon-rds-mysql-unresponsive-every-15-mins-while-gbs-of-space-get-used-and?rq=4